# Discord.py. Как можно сделать embed подобным embed'у на картинке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

[image: Embed]

В целом даже если это нельзя реализовать в коде, я вообще не могу понять как сделать такой черный фон и засунуть картинку в начало. Пытался через css редактировать,но функции редактирования фона там не нашел.

Comment: Поковыряйтесь с полями [тут](https://cog-creators.github.io/discord-embed-sandbox/). Думаю, сможете найти то, что вам нужно. А тёмный фон - это блок кода из разметки Markdown. О подобной разметке можно почитать на вики Markdown

Comment: Спасибо, особенно огромное за этот сайт, я даже не знал что подобные есть. Огромная экономия времени и огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы такое сделать тебе нужно добавить к тексту в начале и конце вот это ```
Надеюсь помог )

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).